# Change DateFormat depending on Days passsed

Tags: android, date, format

Essentially what I have is a string which contains a files Last Modified Date. To get this I'm using:

```
Date lastModDate = new Date(file.lastModified());
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("K:mm a");
String formattedDateString = formatter.format(lastModDate);
```

The end result is somewhat like 6:12 AM. What I want to do is each time a certain period of time is passed, the dateformat must change. E.g.

After 1 Day has gone by, Last Modified Date = ("Format1");

After a Week has gone by, Last Modified Date = ("Format2");

After 2 Weeks have gone by, Last Modified Date = ("Format3");

Does it make sense? If so is someone please be able to show me how it's done. A good example is the native Messaging App. When a message is created, It will show it's Time then after some days gone by the format changes to the Date it was created then the month etc...

I'm trying to do exactly that.

Answer (score 0):

Calculate the difference in time between the last modified date and now:

```
 long duration = lastModDate.getTimeInMillis() - current.getTimeInMillis();
 long sec = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(duration);
 boolean inFuture = sec > 0;
 // Use positive value
 if(!inFuture)
      sec = -sec;
 long minutes = sec / 60  % 60;
 long hours = sec / 3600 % 24;
 long days = sec / 86400;

 if(days > 1 && days < 7)
      // Use format 1
 else if(days >= 7 && days < 14)
      // Use format 2
 else
      // Use format 3
```